# java optimization by compiler or JIT

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

From time to time I see code like this:

```
if (id.split(":").length > 1) {
 sub_id = id.split(":")[1];
 parent_id = id.split(":")[0];
}
```

Wouldn't it be better (and faster) to do something like

```
String [] ids = id.split(":");
if (ids.length > 1) {
  sub_id = ids[1];
  parent_id = ids[0];
}
```

This way you don't have to call 'split()' multiple times, or will the compiler/JIT do such optimizations?

Comment: The optimization engine can improve performance of the algorithm used, but cannot (to my knowledge) replace your code with another algorithm.

Comment: If this is not just a theoretical question, but you have a real need to optimize the code, I would avoid to use the regexp-able split method at all. Using `indexOf` to find the ':' and two `substring` calls to extract each part of the id ought to be much faster than both alternatives.

Answer (score 10):

I certainly wouldn't expect *either* the JIT *or* the compiler do perform such optimizations. It would have to know that:

- The results don't "usefully" change between calls
- Nothing was going to use the fact that each method call produces separate arrays
- Nothing was going to use the fact that each method call produces different string objects

It seems very unlikely that either the JIT or the compiler would optimize for this.

Yes, it's definitely more efficient to use the second form - and I'd argue it's more readable too. When more readable code is also more efficient, that's a pretty clear indication of which code to use ;)

Comment: I'm used to a C and C++ compiler optimizing the hell outta the code. Guess I'll have to find the ones writing such code and tell them to optimize...

Comment: Measure first, then you have hard data instead of waving your arms.

Comment: ... I sometimes get the impression that people expect the compiler to be smarter than it is.

Comment: Thorbjorn: I did a simple test now, the code with the split() was slower. 5 secs on 10000000 iterations, and 0 seconds the other way around.

Comment: @OddBeck: What do you mean by "the code with the split()"? Both versions use `split`. One of them calls it once; the other calls it three times.

Comment: jon skeet: I put id.split(":")[0] in a for loop, and then iterated 10 million times, and then I put the split outside the for-loop, and of course that would finish almost immediatly.

something like this:

    for (int i = 0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
    String s1 = urn.split(":")[1];
    }

Comment: and the other: String []ids = id.split(":"); for(int i =0;i<100000000;i++) { String s = ids[0]; }

Comment: @OddBeck: Why didn't you test the *actual code you presented*? Surely that would be simpler and more useful.

Comment: Good question. Guess my brain just isn't working this morning.

Comment: I don't have the source code at hand to check, but I am pretty sure that the Hotspot optimizer in current Java VMs knows and considers the invariance of at least some of the standard API methods. If the optimizer knows that String#split(String) is invariant and has no side effects, it could easily analyze the code and conclude that the returned array is never changed, hence replacing the three invocations of split with just one.

Comment: @jarnbjo: That would be surprising - and *very* easily observed, just by comparing references. Would love to see evidence that it's happening though.

Comment: The optimization is at least implemented for some of the methods in the Math class. E.g. a loop like `for(double d = 0; d < Math.sin(x); d += 0.001);` will not always invoke Math.sin for each iteration. For some reason (1.7.0_17, 64-bit, server-VM), the optimization only works if x < asin(1/sqrt(2)). You can compare the runtime of the loop with x=0.7 and x=0.8. This optimization is IMHO only possible if the Hotspot knows that Math.sin(x) is invariant for a constant x and that the method has no side effects.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Right, but it's *also* possible because the results really, really can't be distinguished from each other. That's not true with `String.split`.

Comment: No, but knowing that String.split is semantically invariant, it would not really surprise me if the optimizer took it one step further and checked for modifications of the returned array before it decides if the code can be optimized or not. The optimization I mentioned seem however to be limited to loop conditions and a set of well defined mathematical operations. The actual implementation is found in hotspot/src/share/vm/opto/subnode.cpp of the JDK source code.