# Strange behaviour of the Hotspot loop condition optimizer

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, optimization

Based on the discussions around an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339510/java-optimization-by-compiler-or-jit) question, I discovered a really strange behaviour of the Java Hotspot optimizer. The observed behaviour can at least be seen in the Oracle VM 1.7.0_17, but seem to occur in older Java 6 versions as well.

First of all, I was already aware of the optimizer obviously being aware that some methods in the standard API are invariant and have no side effects. When executing a loop like `double x=0.5; for(double d = 0; d < Math.sin(x); d += 0.001);`, the expression `Math.sin(x)` is not evaluated for each iteration, but the optimizer is aware that the method `Math.sin` has no relevant side effects and that the result is invariant, as long as `x` is not modified in the loop.

Now I noticed, that simply changing `x` from 0.5 to 1.0 disabled this optimization. Further tests indicate that the optimization is only enabled if abs(x) < asin(1/sqrt(2)). Is there a good reason for that, which I don't see, or is that an unnecessary limitation to the optimizing conditions?

Edit: The optimization seem to be implemented in hotspot/src/share/vm/opto/subnode.cpp

Comment: How do you know that "the expression Math.sin(x) is not evaluated for each iteration"? Have you looked at the assembly code? Or measured time? Also note that `Math.sin` is an intrinsic method in Java 1.7 (possibly before) so the code run is not the Java code shown in the JDK source...

Comment: @assylias: By measuring time, but you have a good point. I wonder if it is the actual implementation of Math.sin, which is optimized for arguments < asin(1/sqrt(2)) and that it has nothing to do with the loop condition.

Comment: @jarbjo The implementation for x86_64 cpus is here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/6e9aa487055f/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp around line 2878.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question about specifically Oracle JVM, because implementation of Math is implementation-dependent. Here is good answer about Dalvik implementation for example:
[native code for Java Math class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970750/native-code-for-java-math-class)

Generally

1. sin(a) * sin(a) + cos(a) * cos(a) = 1
2. sin(pi/2 - a) = cos(a)
3. sin(-a) = -sin(a)
4. cos(-a) = cos(a)

so we don't need sin/cos functions implementation for x < 0 or x > pi/4.

I suppose this is the answer (https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5005861):

> We are aware of the almabench results and and osnews article on
> trigonometric performance.  However, the HotSpot implementation of
> sin/cos on x86 for years has used and continues to use fsin/fcos x87
> instructions in a range where those instructions meet the quality of
> implementation requirements, basically [-pi/4, pi/4].  Outside of that
> range, the results of fsin/fcos can be anywhere in the range [-1, 1]
> with little relation to the true sine/cosine of the argument.  For
> example, fsin(Math.PI) only gets about half the digits of the result
> correct.  The reason for this is that the fsin/fcos instruction
> implementations use a less than ideal algorithm for *argument
> reduction*; the argument reduction process is explained in bug
> 4857011.

Conclusion: you have seen results of argument reduction algorithm in action, not the limitation of optimization.

Comment: To what extent is the fact that `Math.Sin(Math.Pi)` does not yield precisely zero a "feature"?  I would posit that most real-world code that calls `Math.Sin` does so with arguments that have about a 1/4LSB to 1/2LSB rounding error; argument reduction using `Math.Pi` would counteract this rounding error in most real-world applications, while argument reduction using π preserves it.